# Long polling with URLStream in ActionScript - how to know when to do something with the data?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, long-polling

I'm trying to open a connection to a URL that will periodically send over a JSON object. I know that I need to use URLStream and some event callbacks, but I'm in the dark when it comes to knowing how streams of data "work," or the general flow of operations. Assume I know how to open the connection and send the correct request headers. First, some relevant code:

```
stream = new URLStream();
stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, dataReceived);
stream.load(request);

private function dataReceived(pe:ProgressEvent):void
{
    //now what?
}
```

If the server spurts out JSON objects, how do I know to stop reading one complete object and pass it to another function? How often is dataReceived called? When the server sends something over, does it give an indication how how big the JSON is so you know when to stop? After reading various snippets of code from around the internet, I've determined that these will be major players in this operation:

***pe.bytesLoaded

stream.readUTFBytes(length:String)***
and maybe **pe.bytesTotal**

I guess I don't know how to use them together. Is bytesTotal the total expected size of the incoming complete JSON object? I know so little about this I really don't know what to ask, so I'm just throwing questions out there in a clueless fashion. I've been reading http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLStream.html but the example code is a skeleton of callbacks so it isn't useful.

Hope I've been clear with my question(s), and thanks!

Edit: a single JSON entry is terminated with a carriage return \r

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to understand your question. If the below explanation deviates from yours, just ignore it.

This is a bit low-level on protocol buffering. There may be third party libraries available to transfer json on as3 as such, you can use them (Eg: http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib etc)

Data you receive at your client end may be chunk-ed or you may get all at once. So  in-order to keep track of data size (amount of data you receive), you need to know the size of data server is sending. To do this, we generally code first few bytes (usually 4 bytes) of data with the size of complete data. This might change based on the protocol both client and server have agreed to.

Data = "<4 Bytes >< Rest of the data>"

So once you get the size of data the server is sending, you have to keep an internal buffer to collect the data until it receives the complete data.

I'll tell you how you can do this actionscript.  This was taken from

http://code.google.com/p/cave/source/browse/trunk/cave/wave/org/cestum/cave/presenter/rpc/CaveSocket.as

I have added comments for your understanding...

```
               private function onResponse(e:ProgressEvent):void{
                    trace("Recieved Response");
                    //InputBuffer is socket buffer
                    if (inputBuffer.bytesAvailable == 0)
                            inputBuffer.clear();

                    //copy all bytes from socket buffer, to internal buffer - this way you avoid working on socket buffer internally
                    //and have more control on the pulling data your way. Because server keeps on appending data to socket buffer, 
                    //you may lose control
                    readBytes(inputBuffer, inputBuffer.length, bytesAvailable);

                    //AS3 is single threaded, we'll create a new event for our data 
                    //processing so that socket buffers its data from server seperately.
                    dispatchEvent(new Event("DataComplete"));
            }

            //DataComplete Event
            function onCompleteData(event:Event):void {
                    trace("Complete Data");
                    //We havent got the requires data size from server
                    if (requiredSize == -1) {
                            //Look for first four bytes - that has our data size.
                            if (inputBuffer.bytesAvailable < 4 ) {

                                    return;
                            }
                            var sizeBuffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                            inputBuffer.readBytes(sizeBuffer,0 , 4);        
                            var ipStream1:CodedInputStream = CodedInputStream.newInstance(sizeBuffer);
                            requiredSize = ipStream1.readRawLittleEndian32();
                    }
                    if (requiredSize == -1) return;

                    trace( "Req: " + requiredSize + "   buffer_length: " + buffer.length  + "     bytes_Available: " + inputBuffer.bytesAvailable  + "     bytes_Position: " + inputBuffer.position);

                    //Now you know the size of data server is sending... just extract that amount of data from socket buffer to internal buffer.


                    if ((requiredSize - buffer.length) > inputBuffer.bytesAvailable) {
                            inputBuffer.readBytes(buffer,buffer.length , inputBuffer.bytesAvailable);
                            return;
                    } else {
                            inputBuffer.readBytes(buffer, buffer.length , (requiredSize - buffer.length));
                    }
                    trace("Before processing: " + buffer.length);

              ...Process your data here....


                    requiredSize = -1;
                    lastReadByte = -1;
                    buffer = new ByteArray();
                    if (inputBuffer.bytesAvailable > 0) {
                            onCompleteData(null);
                    }                       
            }
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking the time to comment and explain. It is helpful, especially about buffers. I should say that the protocol I'm using is HTTP, so I guess content-length would indicate how large the response is. I'm not sure how this changes (or if it's even used) since the connection never closes; maybe they send HTTP headers again or maybe they don't. I'm not sure what the difference is between socket buffer and URLStream, and I won't be using a 'complete data' event, right? Since the long polling never really finishes

Comment: The CompleteData function is a misnomer here. It doesn't mean that the data transfer is complete. The server still sends data, once the data is copied to internal buffer, the data processing is delegated to onCompleteData function. Server keeps on sending the data and onCompleteData process the data.

To answer your question, Content-length defines the raw data  length, bytesTotal in your case. If data is chunked, you'll never know when a JSON object is completed. If you relay on HTTP transfer, the use custom header that tells the JSON length and extract the data based on that length.